# Should I be opening a database connection in my controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My controllers need to get data that is passed back to the view. Where should I open a connection to pass to the repository? Here is an example. This is a part of one of my controllers.

```
using (var connection = this.GetActiveConnection())
{
    var repository = new RefRepository(connection);
    var codes = repository.GetPoACodes();    
}
```

Is it bad practice to be opening a connection in the controller? If I don't pass it via the controller, where should I pass the connection to the repository?

Comment: To keep separation of concern totally in honor you should do it within the Model namespace.  Maybe I ask you, why wouldn´t you want to do it within the Model namespace? :)

Comment: Why would you want to pass the connection to the repository? Are you using several dabatases on your app? Is this a multitenant system? If so, this would be a different use case to be analyzed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually Repositories must handle connection themselves, it shouldn't be controller concern.
Controller class must remain thin, and if it gets fat, it would be a code smell.

It would a very good practice if you can use a Dependency Injection Framework (like Ninject, StructureMap, ...) to wire those dependencies , to handle DbContext or Session and SessionFactory (EF or NHibernate), Transaction or namely Unit of Work pattern, Exception Handling and Logging if you want to go thus far.

If you're using Visual Studio then in Project Templates there is an option which create repositories also, you can create a sample project, read the code, and learn how the code is organized.

In this [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-an-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-ef-and-webapi/), under Web API header, you can find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not open a database connection on your controller.

Controller should talk to your "domain model", which is not the same as your database schema.

In your case, maybe your repository must handle it.

Or even more, if your using Entity Framework or NHibernate, for example, it'd be better let them handle that matter.